# How do I use the Pen tool to subtract from shape in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, effects, pen-tool

I'm following [this](http://designstacks.net/how-to-create-3d-love-text-composition) tutorial and I got stuck in this step

> Using the same Pen Tool (P) in a new layer we must represent the
>   frontal part for letter “O”. Firstly we need to draw the outer shape
>   of the letter “O” and close off the path, then select the path in
>   Paths panel, go to Pen Tool (P), choose Subtract from shape area
>   option from Options bar and draw in where the hole should be.

How do I achieve that step?

[Here](https://youtu.be/No11c0Bj4KI) is my attempt to follow the instruction... what am I doing wrong??

I'm using Photoshop CC 2015

Comment: Exactly as the quote says... I'm not sure how else to explain. What exactly are you stuck on? Could you maybe [edit] with some screenshots of what you have and what you can't do?

Comment: Well.. I did what the tutorial says and got stuck because either I don't understand well or photoshop behaves different, and good suggestion, I'll add more details

Comment: Done, I added a small video of my attempt

Comment: Try doing the outside of the D (From the video), then the inside, then use the Path Selection Tool (A), to select both paths, then right click on the new shape you just made, then click on "Fill Subpaths"

Comment: Are you down voting these answers? I see no reason for either to be at -1.  Just because you might not agree with what someone has said, does not mean it is wrong or the user deserves to [lose reputation](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) over it.  Please save down votes for incomplete, poorly researched, spam, blatantly incorrect, etc. answers.

Comment: I'm not downvoting, i can't even upvote... My question got downvoted and i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the option you are looking for.
When you select the pen tool, it is the second icon in the option bar.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it should work fine if you select *both* paths and select "Fill Path.." instead of only selecting the inside path and filling the subpath, as that ignores the outer path, however...

What you should be doing is using a shape layer instead. From the dropdown at the top left where it says "Path", change that to "Shape". This will create a vector shape layer that you don't need to manually fill. You can then edit your shape as much as you like without having to redo any fills and it will be a lot easier to change and understand the shape modes of your subpaths.